# Deploy minified source to github-pages

Tags: git, github, gruntjs

I'm having trouble figuring out how best to deploy a minified build to gh-pages, but keeping a development build in master.

I have a repository with this format:

```
/build
/public
  /stylesheets
     a bunch of scss files
  /javascript
     a bunch of js files
  index.html
gruntfile.js
```

during development, I have a grunt task that watches everything and creates built files that are unminified. My build folder during dev looks like this

```
/build
  index.html
  main.js
  styles.css
```

I then have a grunt task for creating a production build that minifies my javascript and css and then inlines into my index.html file. Giving me a build directory of simly

```
/build
  index.html
```

I need to be able to deploy the production, minfied build folder to a gh-pages branch without destroying the history of the repo. Ideally the master branch would not include the build folder at all.

I know that I can deploy a subtree using `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`, the issue is having the correct version of the build folder in the correct branch.

Answer (score 0):

The post at this url is very useful: https://github.com/X1011/git-directory-deploy

The important bits: Since I don't want the build folder checked in, and I want to keep it in the .gitignore, subtree pushing doesn't make sense. This answer also allows you to have an opportunity to build production files before pushing that are never seen in master.

Assuming that your `dist` folder is where your production files are, here is how to get set up.

`git --work-tree dist checkout --orphan gh-pages`
First create a gh-pages branch that has no history and is separate from other branches (an orphan)

`git --work-tree dist rm -r "*"`
Remove the normal source files from the branch

`git --work-tree dist add --all`
Add only the files that are in `dist`

`git --work-tree dist commit -m "initial publish"`

`git push origin gh-pages`

`git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master && git reset --mixed`
reset back to master

And for additional deploys

`git checkout gh-pages`

`git --work-tree dist add --all`

`git --work-tree dist commit -m "Commit Message"`

`git push origin gh-pages`

`git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master && git reset --mixed`